# Chart.js with 2 y-axis

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to get my simple chart to have the same y axis display on both sides, i can't seem to get this right without adding another graph.

is it possible to get it working with just 1 graph?

```
data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 10, 15, 5],
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        yAxisID: 'A'

    },{
        // This dataset appears on the second axis
        yAxisID: 'B',
    }]
},

// Configuration options go here
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        id: 'B',
        position: 'right',
        gridLines: {
            zeroLineColor:'#131c2b'
        }   
    },{
        id: 'A',
        position: 'left',
        gridLines: {
            zeroLineColor:'#131c2b'
        }   
    },]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by updating the right yAxis min and max values. Right now it only gets updated at the beginning, so it's not responsive. You have to call `updateOptions()` everytime you change your chart (e.g. when you hide datasets)...

[Here is my code (JSBin)](https://jsbin.com/toyezipuga/edit?html,js,output)

```
function updateOptions() {
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[1].ticks = {
    min: chart.scales.A.ticksAsNumbers[chart.scales.A.ticksAsNumbers.length-1],
    max: chart.scales.A.ticksAsNumbers[0]
  }
  chart.update()
}
```