# chart.js - show duplicate y-axis on left and right sides

Tags: javascript, chart.js

*I know similar questions have been asked many times before, but most results are for older versions and the API has changed a lot. I could not find code for 3.5+ that "just works".*

I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve what I want.

I have multiple datasets mapped to one y-axis in `chart.js`. This works well as we chart them to compare them across time (x-axis) and value. The y-axis expands based on all datasets.

I had a request to simply duplicate the labels so they show on both the left and right side. This does not seem to be simple as axes are mapped to datasets one-to-one.

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525418/2060441 and updating it for my version of `chart.js` I came up with the below. **Is there a better way?** It feels very clunky. Notably once the chart options become an object, updating the min/max directly doesn't appear to work so I have to replace it wholesale.

```
// add a dummy dataset, use legend.labels.filter to stop them showing
datasets.push({ yAxisID: 'yAxis2' });
            
// we need to attach to the chart and update *before* we get min/max, in case the data bounds changed
forecast_chart.data.datasets = datasets;
forecast_chart.update();

minTick = forecast_chart.scales.yAxis1.min;
maxTick = forecast_chart.scales.yAxis1.max;

forecast_chart.options.scales.yAxis2 =
{
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'right',
    min: minTick,
    max: maxTick,
    ticks:
    {
        stepSize: 50,
    
    };
};
forecast_chart.update();
forecast_chart.resize();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
scales: {
  y: {
    position: "left",
  },
  y1: {
    position: "right",
    afterBuildTicks: (axis) => {
      axis.ticks = [...axis.chart.scales.y.ticks];
      axis.min = axis.chart.scales.y.min;
      axis.max = axis.chart.scales.y.max;
    },
  },
}
```